# Ruby knock gem integration with devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise, jwt

My goal is to implement knock jwt implementation with existing devise user model.
I followed README.md instructions from knock github project:
https://github.com/nsarno/knock

When I send, using curl, jwt authentication request for existing user:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:3000/knock/auth_token --data ' {"auth": {"email": "user@example.com", "password": "password"}} ' —verbose`

I got following exception:

`ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):
  devise (3.4.1) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:147:in password_digest'
  activemodel (4.2.5.2) lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:103:in authenticate'`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: For those still coming across this thread: [This issue on Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/70) provides several examples on how to add Knock/authorization tokens to an app now servicing an API on top of the initial web authentication layer using Devise.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating following link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

this is important piece of information:

> Adds methods to set and authenticate against a BCrypt password. This mechanism requires you to have a password_digest attribute.

Since devise uses in user model method:

`encrypted_password`

you need in User active model create following method:

```
def password_digest
    self.encrypted_password
end
```

Comment: If I put in my "app/models/user.rb" file this: `class User < ApplicationRecord   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable (etc...)   def password_digest    self.encrypted_password  end  end` it gives to me an error when I use User.create! method for example in seeds: `rails aborted! ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) /app/models/user.rb:7:in password_digest'
/bundle/bundler/gems/devise-9c0dccfec1b4/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:40:in 'password='` How to fix this? Can I really use devise and knock gem?